# TCPClient async/await C#

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient

I have several devices. The program must constantly ping these devices.

Faced a problem - if the connection is lost, then my program does not display anything except the first poll before the connection is lost, and if I restore the connection, then after 15 seconds the program will start to output data.

```
public async Task Start(string ip)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Begin");
        textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            watch.Restart();
            using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcp.SendTimeout = 1000;
                try
                {
                    await tcp.ConnectAsync("192.168.127.23", 10001);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Debug.Assert(!tcp.Connected);
                }

                watch.Stop();
                if (tcp.Connected)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(i.ToString() + ") " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
                    textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}) Offline", i));
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

This is a new code, with my additions.

```
public async Task Start(string ip)
    {   
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < devicesListActivity.Count; i++)
            {
                devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing++;

                string ipAdresDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesName;
                int portDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesPort;
                int activeDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesActiv;
                int imageDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesImage;
                int sendTimeDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTimeSend;
                int respTimeDevice = devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTimeResp;

                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(sendTimeDevice);
                var ct = cts.Token;

                var t = await Task.Run<ServerStatus>(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
                        {
                            client.ConnectAsync(ipAdresDevice, portDevice).Wait(sendTimeDevice);
                            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            client.Close();
                            return ServerStatus.Available;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(SocketException))
                    {
                        if (((SocketException)ex.InnerException).SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionRefused)
                            return ServerStatus.Refused;
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Server did not respond");
                        }

                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        return ServerStatus.TimeOut;
                    }
                }, ct);

                switch (t)
                {
                    case ServerStatus.Available:
                        devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing++;
                        textBox1.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Server available" + " " + ipAdresDevice + string.Format(" [{0}/{1}]", devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing, devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing) + " " + System.Math.Round((double)(devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing / devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing * 100)) +" %");
                        textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                        break;
                    case ServerStatus.Refused:
                        textBox1.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Server refused connection." + " " + ipAdresDevice + string.Format(" [{0}/{1}]", devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing, devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing) + " " + System.Math.Round((double)(devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing / devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing * 100)) + " %");
                        textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                        break;
                    case ServerStatus.TimeOut:
                        textBox1.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Server did not respond." + " " + ipAdresDevice + string.Format(" [{0}/{1}]", devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing, devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing) + " " + System.Math.Round((double)(devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesSuccessPing / devicesListActivity[i].DevicesList.DevicesTotalPing * 100)) + " %");
                        textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                        break;
                }

                // Wait 1 second before trying the test again
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You described the current behavior. What is the behavior you actually want to see/achieve?

Comment: @MouseOnMars I want to see that when the connection fails, it is displayed offline for each attempt. I'm sorry I forgot to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the way that TCP Connect works.  When you do a `client.ConnectAsync()` the operating system will take a period of time to actually time out.  Your setting of `tcp.SendTimeout = 1000;` has no effect on the `ConnectAsync()` which is managed by the operating system which can be 20 seconds.

So what's happening in this case is that you're bringing the server back on line before the connect has timed out and the connect connects.

So unless want to wait 20 seconds to be alerted, you're going to need to run another timeout to cancel the pending Connect() and report that you are offline.  Eg, if you don't get a response in 1 second, the report offline.

Also if the connection fails due to it being actively refused you'll need to handle that test case as well.  Refused generally means that your server is up, but the port is not listening.  However it could also be a firewall actively refusing the connection, in which case you don't know if the server is up.

Consider the following code example which achieves basic TCP monitoring of a port:

```
private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int timeOut = 2000;

    while (true)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            var ca = client.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 9999);
            await Task.WhenAny(ca, Task.Delay(timeOut));
            client.Close();
            if (ca.IsFaulted || !ca.IsCompleted)
                listBox1.Items.Add($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Server offline.");
            else
                listBox1.Items.Add($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Server available.");
        }
        // Wait 1 second before trying the test again
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it does almost as it should, but there is one question. If the connection is lost, then the operator `throw` goes through exception. I added this `throw new Exception("Server did not respond");`, but of course, nothing is output. Please tell me how to fix it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just found one interesting point. I slightly changed your code to fit my needs and now strange things are happening, I want to ping two devices, one definitely works, and the second doesn't. The first three times it is displayed normally that a non-working device is not connected, but then it is displayed that there is a connection. Tell me what the trouble is. I have added new code to my question.

Comment: And sometimes it immediately displays that there is a connection.

Comment: Most likely I broke something in your code, because now even if you disable the working device, it still displays that there is a connection ... =)

Comment: Hi. You need to turn off runtime exceptions in the debugger. We're using exceptions as part of the program flow, this is frowned upon, but for Socket you don't have a choice because that's how the socket is designed. Those exceptions won't occur in a production release.

Comment: Your stomping on the exception. Always rethrow with ``throw;`` so you can see the exception type. it's possible/likely that the socket is returning some other type of exception, have a look at that exception and add the appropriate handler. You could create a generic ``return ServerStatus.UnknownError``

Comment: Hello. I realized that I should leave the operator as it was. Right? I returned it as it was, but still after some time, not correct addresses show that the connection is available.I probably misunderstood something ...

Comment: Are you catching any other exceptions from the Task.Run() ? You could try adding a ``catch { return ServerStatus.UnknownError }`` and change the ``throw`` to ``return ServerStatus.UnknownError``

Comment: I have simplified this, given what you're trying to do and how you're trying to use it, this might be better.  it's also a bit slicker.

Comment: I replaced each catch with one universal, in the hope that so to receive all errors that arise. But anyway, it turns out that the wrong address is connecting ...

Comment: The code above won't give you any exceptions and is faster and more efficient because it does not use Task.Run or Task.Wait.